# turn off aura lightsfor asus rog ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, asus, keyboard-backlight

I am using ASUS ROG g531gd
How do I turn off the ASUS ROG Aura lights, they are really eating up my battery.

New versions of BIOS settings do not allow me to turn off the lights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git clone https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore.git
cd rogauracore
sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo apt install autoconf
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
sudo make install # Shutdown and restart the system
# Rainbow
sudo rogauracore rainbow
# Usage:
sudo rogauracore COMMAND ARGUMENTS
# COMMAND should be one of:
single_static
single_breathing
single_colorcycle
multi_static
multi_breathing
red
green
blue
yellow
cyan
magenta
white
black
rainbow
```

Courtesy [Setting up ubuntu on asus rog](https://medium.com/@itzpallab/setting-up-ubuntu-18-04-on-my-rog-strix-a-short-review-7c93983f6d04)

The following command switched off the light

`sudo rogauracore black`

Edits: correct minor code typos.