# asusctl on Ubuntu 22.04 not working on Asus ROG Strix G513QY

Tags: keyboard, asus, 22.04, keyboard-backlight

After upgrading ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04 the keyboard leds have been shutoff and it's almost impossible to see key labels. No leds with this model is a poor choice. The leds cycle as normal when booting, or accessing the the BIOS settings.

I build and installed asusctl from GitLab repo, knowing it doesn't support ubuntu, but was hoping it would work..

```
ROG-Strix:~/Projects/Gitlab/asusctl$ sudo systemctl status asusd


● asusd.service - ASUS Notebook Control
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/asusd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-04-28 22:48:44 EDT; 16min ago
    Process: 741 ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 913 (asusd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 76373)
     Memory: 2.7M
        CPU: 970ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/asusd.service
             └─913 /usr/bin/asusd
```

I have tried:

```
sudo asusctl led-mode static -c ff00ff
```

and most other combinations with no luck, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this stackoverflow [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217614/turn-off-aura-lightsfor-asus-rog-ubuntu-18-04) :
and their github [site](https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore)

It suggested that the problem might be that the keyboard brightness was set to 0, and that indeed was the problem!

So now

asusctl led-mode

changes can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

I was dual-booting Windows and had enabled Aura Sync as lighting controller from ROG Armoury Crate. This disabled the keyboard backlight in Linux.
Went back to Windows, switched "Lighting" to "Device - System - Static" and lights are back on in Ubuntu also.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Asus ROG Strix g533zw and doing this helped me.

First I needed to find my `prod_family`. Open your terminal and type `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name` and it will output a string containing the prod_family
Mine was `ROG Strix G533ZW_G533ZW`, I assumed that my prod_family is `ROG Strix`
Next  find the `board_name` by typing `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/board_name`, mine was `G533ZW`

Then open `/etc/asusd/asusd-ledmodes.toml` find the led_mode family of your production and add your board_name to the array if it is not present, then delete `/etc/asusd/aura.conf` and type `systemctl restart asusd` to restart the asus daemon. After that reopen the terminal and try typing `asusctl led-mode static -c ffffff`. Hope this will help

Comment: Followed instructions exactly , my computer model was listed in the toml file but 
sudo asusctl led-mode static -c ffffff

still has not effect.